# How to solve Intent Redirection Vulnerability in android apk?

Tags: android, security, redirect, android-intent, android-security

I created my app in Unity, then exported project and then I generated signed apk in Android Studio.

I wanted to upload my app to Google Play store, but it has been rejected because of  security vulnerabilities.

The vulnerability is **Intent Redirection** and I was recommended to follow one of these steps:
https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9267555

My app uses firebase (db and auth) and I suppose that this could cause the vulnerability (but Im not sure, because my Alerts in Play Console are empty). But how can I fix this problem?

I tried to add  android:exported=”false” to my Manifest file, but it only contains one activity, which is probably my whole app created in Unity. So when I added  android:exported=”false” to this activity, I wasnt able to install my app (I found why [Android Manifest's android:exported="false" prevents app from running on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49471423/android-manifests-androidexported-false-prevents-app-from-running-on-device))

My database manager looks like this:

```
public class DatabaseManager : MonoBehaviour
```

{

```
public static DatabaseManager sharedInstance = null;

private void Awake()
{
    if (sharedInstance == null)
    {
        sharedInstance = this;
    }
    else if (sharedInstance != this)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://addresstomydatabase.com/");
```

}

Comment: What should we do if we use react-native? We cannot find which package causes this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I received an asnwer from google play support and the vulnerability was caused by xiaomi dependecies.

Here is how to solve this problem:
[Your app contains an Intent Redirection vulnerability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56175958/your-app-contains-an-intent-redirection-vulnerability/56274895#56274895)