# Android App to start automatically on Boot Up

Tags: android

I am trying to get my Android app to start automatically on boot up.
I have followed various examples and copied the code, but still, when I power up, the app does NOT start.

I am using a Galaxy Tab A7 Lite, running Android 11.

Any help gladly received.

Thank you.

Here is my code...

I have defined the receiver:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class StartOnBootupReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(activityIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

And in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

and

```
<receiver android:name=".StartOnBootupReceiver"
    android:exported="false"
    >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action..QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: note that "android.intent.action..QUICKBOOT_POWERON" has two "." instead of one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks good and your receiver is most likely executing. However, it is crashing because of the call to `startActivity()`. Since Android 10, `startActivity()` can only be called if the application is already in the Foreground or if it meets one of the listed exceptions listed in the Android guide [Restrictions on starting activities from the background](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts#exceptions).

As an aside, the value of the `android:exported` has no effect. The OS can still call receivers who have `android:exported="false"` and, in the case of `exported="true"`, other application cannot send a broadcast with `BOOT_COMPLETED` or `QUICKBOOT_COMPLETED` because they are protected intent actions.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I understand why they would want to restrict this. However, what I want to do with my app is as follows: Use a Samsung tablet as a user interface to a machine. The tablet would be fitted to the body of the machine etc. So when the tablet power sup, I want it to launch the app automatically etc. I also want to try and hide the bottom navigation bar permanently. All this because the display I used to use for this machine is no longer available, because some of the chips are no longer available, so I thought that using a tablet might solve the problem.

Comment: @garrettb In which case you want to look into making your app the Device Owner or use the [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management). This is one of the exceptions listed and will allow to have much more control over the device. Specifically, I believe you are looking for [Kiosk Mode](https://developers.google.com/android/management/policies/dedicated-devices#kiosk_mode).

Comment: Excellent - thank you for that feedback - I guess that's all I really need to know for now - and I will go and do my research. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Android 10, the startActivity method only works if it is called by an application that is in the foreground. So you can request the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION" />
```

Now request the REQUEST_OVERLAY_PERMISSION if android version is above 10:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q && !Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
      val intent = Intent(
          Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
          Uri.parse("package:$packageName")
      )
      startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_OVERLAY_PERMISSION)
}
```

Once the permission is granted you can again use the startActivity method from your BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: This did the trick for me under Android 13, the only additional thing I had to do was add FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to the intent.

Answer (score 0):

All your code is correct. However, if you look up `android:exported="false" meaning` you will find that:

> The "exported" attribute describes whether or not someone else can be allowed to use it. So if you have "exported=false" on an Activity, no other app, or **even the Android system itself**, can launch it. Only you can do that, from inside your own application.

In your `<receiver>` statment, the `android:exported="false"` needs to be `true`.

That info borrowed [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49471423/android-manifests-androidexported-false-prevents-app-from-running-on-device) and [here](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=android%3Aexported%20%3D%20false%20meaning).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Omeage_Pixel. However, I had already tried the above code with the 'exported=true', and indeed I have just re-tried that. However, the app still does not start after I restart the tablet.

Comment: By the way - I wonder am I misunderstanding something. Essentially what I want is for my app to launch automatically after the tablet powers up - which is why I am trying the above code etc.

Comment: It is doable, there are a bunch of posts all over the internet on how to do that... I'm assuming that you've already scoured the web, but this post may be of help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391902/how-do-i-start-my-app-when-the-phone-starts-on-android. Apparently, android 10 introduced a permissions requirement.

Comment: Yes, I've been through those examples, still no luck. If anyone else reads this comment, I am still looking for a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The problem was solved when I got the following permission.

```
private fun requestPermission() {
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
        val intent = Intent(
            Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
            Uri.parse("package:" + this.packageName)
        )
        startActivityForResult(intent, 232)
    } else {
        //Permission Granted-System will work
    }
}
```

}