How to auto launch Flutter app at device boot?
I'd like my Flutter/Kotlin application to be able to launch and display automatically when my Android 9 and higher device starts up.
I've tried the broadcastReceiver but it doesn't work, I receive the logs but it doesn't visually launch the application.
I add autorization to my Manifest
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

and declaration of my BroadcastReceiver
    <receiver
            android:name=".BootBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

I created two classes, a class BroadcastReceiver who get boot_complete
    import androidx.work.OneTimeWorkRequest
    import androidx.work.WorkManager
    import androidx.work.WorkRequest

    class BootBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            if (intent != null) {
                if(intent.action == Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) {
                    Log.d("BootBroadcastReceiver", "Boot completed. Scheduling app       launch.")

                // Planifier un travail pour démarrer l'application après un délai
                    val workRequest: WorkRequest =     OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(AppLaunchWorker::class.java).build()
                    if (context != null) {
                        WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(workRequest)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

and a class AppLaunchWorker who launch the app
    import android.content.Context
    import android.content.Intent
    import androidx.work.Worker
    import androidx.work.WorkerParameters
    import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

    class AppLaunchWorker(context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) :      Worker(context, workerParams) {
        override fun doWork(): Result {
            // Lancer FlutterActivity après que le système ait démarré
            val launchIntent = FlutterActivity.createDefaultIntent(applicationContext)
            launchIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK // Nécessaire pour     démarrer l'activité depuis un contexte non interactif
            applicationContext.startActivity(launchIntent)

            // Retourner un résultat de succès
            return Result.success()
        }
    }

i can see the log but the app dont open visually
    Log.d("BootBroadcastReceiver", "Boot completed. Scheduling app launch.")


Do you have Handled Android 9+ Restrictions ? Battery optimizer and/or auto-start in the settings of the phone ?

android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION
android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
did you granted the permission?
look like your problem is similar to
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72972225/android-app-to-start-automatically-on-boot-up

Thank you both for your help im checking that

I think I understood that since Android 9 it was impossible to have the application open automatically in the foreground and that this required at least a notification to open the application, could someone confirm this?

I'm not sure, as AndroidAuto auto open even from locked screen. So it may be possible to do the same. I've looked up, but didn't find anything interesting at the moment.

Thank you for this information and helping me, i'll look this way.

Here's a github repo that explains how to start an app after boot up in Kotlin.
You may encounter issues on some recent Android versions and devices because of how OEM is managing battery optimization.

I've tried several things but nothing has worked so far..
